# Partial differential equation question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the equation $$u_y + {2u_x}_y=0$$. Using the substituting of $$ v=u_y$$ and making it become an ODE.

Comment: Well, obviously if we plug in $v = u_y$, we get $v + 2v_x = 0$, which we can rewrite as $v + 2{dv \over dx} = 0$. Move the $v$ to the other side and separate the variables.

Comment: Is my solution of making
$$du/dy=ce^{−x/2}$$
and then rearrange and integrating and then solving for u right?

Answer (score 0):

If you take $v=u_y$ you have
$$
v+2\frac{dv}{dx}=0
$$
A separable ode
$$
v+2\frac{dv}{dx}=0\Rightarrow v=-2\frac{dv}{dx}\Rightarrow dx=-2\frac{dv}{v}\Rightarrow \ln(v)=\frac{-1}{2}x+c\Rightarrow v=Ae^{\frac{-1}{2}x}
$$

Comment: In order to solve the general solution, I rearrange for A, but I'm lost on what to do next. :/

Comment: Is my solution of making $$du/dy = ce^{-x/2}$$ and then rearrange and integrating and then solving for u right?